# Lorentz transformation of a trajectory

Tags: special-relativity

I am having trouble understanding how to apply the Lorentz transformation to a particle trajectory.

Suppose we have a body moving in one dimension in one frame where the position is given by $x(t) = f(t)$. Then if we apply a Lorentz transformation with velocity $v$ in the $\hat x$ direction, the trajectory in the boosted frame is $x'(t) = \gamma(v)[ x(t) - vt ] = \gamma(v) [ f(t) - vt ]$.

What I'm having trouble understanding is how to properly parametrize the time coordinate in the boosted frame. According to the Lorentz transformation, we have $ t' = \gamma(v) [ t - v f(t) / c^2 ]$. This implicitly defines $ t = g(t')$. Is the correct trajectory in the boosted frame then given by $x'(t') = \gamma(v)[ f(g(t')) - vg(t') ]$? Is this the correct procedure to generally Lorentz transform a given trajectory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your explanation is right. Moreover, the function you call $g$ always exists because of the implicit function theorem. You can easily see that $t'=F(t)$ satisfies $F'(t)\neq 0$. Here $F(t)=\gamma(v)[t-\frac{vf(t)}{c^{2}}]$, so $F'(t)=\gamma(v)[1-\frac{v}{c}\frac{f'(t)}{c}]$, but remembering that $f'(t)$ is the velocity of the body in the first sistem so must be less than $c$ an consequently the fractions are less than $1$.

Explicitly find $g$ depends on the trayectory, but may be in simple examples you can do it.

Comment: Excellent point about the implicit function theorem. I was wondering if the inverse was always defined.